# Galois group $G_{L/K}$ of unramified extension and its residue fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions, local-field

several weeks ago I [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3418597/galois-groups-g-knr-k-and-g-bark-k-identical-from-silvermans-ari) about a statement form Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves", Cap. VII.4 (The Action of Inertia) recall, we consider a  local complete separable field $K$ with residue field $k$. Furthermore, we denote by $K^{nr}$ the maximal unramified extension of $K$.

I asked about the claim why the Galois groups $G_{K^{nr}/K}$ and $G_{\overline{k}/k}$ are equal. Recall, that $\overline{k}$ is the algebraic closure. as correctly pointed out by Ferra in his answer the argument can be looked up at [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_extensions_of_local_fields#Unramified_extension).

now I would like to know if the isomorphism between $G_{K^{nr}/K}$ an be constructed $G_{\overline{k}/k}$ more directly in a way I would like to explain now:

assume that $K$ if finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$; thus the residue field $k$ is finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$ and thus of characteristic $p$. 
as 
$$G_{K^{nr}/K}= \varprojlim_{L/K \text{ unramified finite ext }}G_{L/K}$$ and $$G_{\overline{k}/k}= \varprojlim_{l/k \text{ finite ext }}G_{L/K}$$

are inverse limits we can reduce our claim to finite case, i.e. we want to see that for any *unramified finite* extension $L/K$ and induced extension $l/k$ of residue fields we want construct the isomorphism $Gal_{L/K}=Gal_{l/k}$ explicitly.

Q: can the isomorphisms $Gal_{L/K}=Gal_{l/k}$ be constructed 'directly'? what I mean by directly? well, $l/k$ is an extension between finite fields with characteristic $p$ and thus there exist $s <n$ with $k= \mathbb{F}_{p^s}, l= \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ and the Galois group $Gal_{l/k}$ is concretely generated by relative Frobenius $\sigma^s$ where $\sigma$ is the Frobenius automorphism given by $a \mapsto \sigma(a)=a^p$ defined for all fields of characteristic $p$.

back to my Question: from above we know that $Gal_{L/K}=Gal_{l/k}$ and my question is what is the 'canonical' generator $\alpha \in Gal_{L/K}$ that is the unique lift of relative Frobenius $\sigma^s$. can the constrution of $\alpha$ from $\sigma^s$ be described explicitely?

Comment: @user714237:nice, thus by given assumptions we also can conclude, that all finite unramified extensions arise as adjunction of a root of unity! one argument on why should $L = K(\zeta_{q^f - 1})$ hold I not understand. using Hensel's lemma we can indeed lift all roots of $X^{q^f-1}-1$ in $l$ to $L$. thus $K(\zeta_{q^f - 1}) \subset L$. why holds the other inclusion?

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3392422/completion-of-bbbq-p-zeta-infty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If $f\in \Bbb{Z}_p[x]_{monic}$ is separable $\bmod p$ then $f\bmod p$'s splitting field is $\Bbb{F}_{p^f} = \Bbb{F}_p(\xi_{p^f-1})$ and (by Hensel lemma) $f$ splits completely in $\Bbb{Z}_p[\zeta_{p^f-1}]$
- Thus $$\Bbb{Z}_p^{unr}=\Bbb{Z}_p[\zeta_{p^\infty-1}]=\bigcup_{p\ \nmid\ n} \Bbb{Z}_p[\zeta_n]=\bigcup_N \{\sum_{j\ge 0} c_j p^j, c_j \in S_N\}$$ where $$S_N=\{0\} \cup \{ \zeta_n,n\le N, p\nmid n\}\}$$
- The lift of $Frob \in Gal(\overline{\Bbb{F}}_p/\Bbb{F}_p)$ to $\phi \in Gal(\Bbb{Z}_p^{unr}/\Bbb{Z}_p)$ is $$\phi(\sum_{j\ge 0} c_j p^j) = \sum_{j\ge 0} c_j^p p^j$$ and $$Gal(\Bbb{Z}_p^{unr}/\Bbb{Z}_p)= \varprojlim \phi^{\Bbb{Z/nZ}}$$

It works the same way in any complete (or Henselian) DVR $R$ with residue field $R/(\pi)\subset \overline{\Bbb{F}}_p$, replacing $p^j$ by $\pi^j$.

Comment: one remark: since $k$ and $l$ are finite fields of char $p$ with $\vert l \vert =q=p^n$ and let $f=[l:k]$, then we know that $l= k(\zeta_{q^f-1})$. as you said, by Hensel's lemma $X^{q^f-1}-1$ also splits in $L$, thus $K(\zeta_{q^f - 1}) \subset L$. why the other inclusion $L \subset K(\zeta_{q^f - 1})$ is also true? although $[l:k]= [L:K]$ by definition of 'unramified', it might possibly (???) happen that $X^{q^f-1}-1$ is not irreducible over $K$ and thus to obtain $L$ from $K(\zeta_{q^f - 1})$ it might be neccessary to adjoin a further element, right? or this case can never occure?